# Math is not outputting correctly

Tags: c

I am still learning to code and wrote this code to get the total after the weight and distance are calculated. Can someone tell my why the math is not working?

Example: When I enter 5 for weight and 1500 miles instead of getting 8.20 back I get 3.50.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double weight,mileCost;
    int miles, segment, remainder, stop = 1;

    while(stop == 1){

    printf("Charge by weight:(We don't tale packages over 10lbs\n");
    printf("\n 1-2 lbs: $1.50\n 3-6 lbs: $3.70\n 7-10 lbs: $5.25\n ");
    printf("Enter your package's weight:\n");
            scanf("%f", &weight);


    printf("Charge by mile: \n");
    printf("$1.50 for every 500 miles\n");
    printf("Enter the total miles for your package:\n");
        scanf("%d", &miles);

    if(miles == 0 || weight == 0 || weight > 10){
            printf("Invalid entry! Try Again.");
        }

        segment= ceil((double) miles / 500);
        remainder = miles % 500;    
            if(remainder > 0)
                remainder = 1;


    if(weight <= 2){
        mileCost = 1.50 * (segment + remainder);
        printf("The shipping charge for your package is: %f\n", mileCost);
        }
    else if(weight > 2 && weight <= 6){
            mileCost = 3.70 * (segment + remainder);
            printf("The shipping charge for your package is: %f\n", mileCost);
        }
    if(weight > 6 && weight <= 10){
            mileCost = 5.25 * (segment + remainder);
            printf("The shipping charge for your package is: %f\n", mileCost);
        }
    system("pause");

    printf("Would you like to ship another package?\n Enter 1 to continue or 0 to stop. \n");
        scanf("%d", &stop);

    if(stop == 0){
    printf("Thank you for your business! \n");
    }
}
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger to see where it's going wrong? This is a lot of code to review.

Comment: Tip: Break up your huge `main()` function into smaller functions that have a well-defined and singular purpose. These are significantly easier to test, then integrate once proven to be working correctly.

Comment: I get a warning on your code: `../main.c:16:17: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]
`

Comment: Possibly not a reason for the issue you see right now, but always check the return value of `scanf`!

Comment: `gcc -lm main.c -> ./a.out` I get 4.50000 So you should check your math and the expected path may not be what you think it is. I would check in gdb.

Comment: Always use brackets around if-statements, even single line ones. Avoid future headaches.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be 11.1 because 
`3.7 * ((miles/500) + (miles % 500)) = 3.7 * (3 + 0) = 11.1`?

Comment: *"instead of getting 8.20"* Do you mean that the correct formula should be 3.7 **+** 1.5 * (1500/500) = 8.2?

Answer (score 2):

Changing `double weight, mileCost;` to `float weight, mileCost;` will make it work since you are reading the variable from `stdin` using `scanf("%f", &weight)` (for floats) and not `scanf("%lf", &weight)` (for double).

I am still puzzled by why you do this:

```
if(remainder > 0)
    remainder = 1;
```

Wouldn't `ceil()` already handle that in:

```
segment = ceil((double) miles / 500);
```

Also, based on the formula you provided, inputting `weight=5` and `miles=1500` should output `11.1`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use "lf" for a reading of a double variable:

```
scanf("%lf", &weight);
```